# How to update value with reducer?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I would like to create a reducer that updates the value of a variable.

So far I have this but I don't know which code to use to update the value:

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const initialStateValue = {
        value: ''
    }

    const benutzerSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'user',
        initialState: initialStateValue,
        reducers: {
            changeValue: (state = initialStateValue) => {
               state.value;
            },
        }
    });

    export const {changeValue} = userSlice.actions;
    export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: How do you want to update the value? Does your chageValue action receive a payload describing the change? Or is it always changed in the same way?

Comment: I have an input field in one of my screens where the user can type in the username and submit it via a button.

Comment: And is the value that the user submits passed in the action payload?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know how to do that.

Comment: I would highly recommend walking through a simple tutorial on react and redux until you're familiar with the basic concepts. When you call dispatch with your action creator, are you passing the input the user submits? e.g. `dispatch(changeValue(userValue))`

Comment: I have to admit I struggle a bit with React, I'll look into it again. `dispatch(changeValue(userValue)`is indeed what I would've done, my problem is that I don't know which code to use for the reducer. I have a similar situation where I set the temperature and the code I use in the reducer is `increaseTemp: (state = initialStateValue) => {state.value++}` (and -- for decreaseTemp) and I already worked out how to use it in the screen (`dispatch(increaseTemp())`). I just don't know how to set a new value for the username within the reducer so that I can use changeValue in the screen.

Comment: I answered a similar question here.. Perhaps it will help you further your understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276113/problem-with-expected-0-arguments-but-got-1-in-redux-toolkit/72280584#72280584

Comment: That helps me a lot, thanks!