# Problem with expected 0 arguments, but got 1 in Redux Toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I have an error `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.` in simple Redux Slice file.

This error occurs when I try to dispatch.

**App.tsx**

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getMovies({ query: "searchQuery", page: 1 }));
  }, []);
```

**Slice.tsx**

```
const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getMovies(name) {
      return name;
    },
    setMovies: (state, action: PayloadAction<Movie[]>) => {
      state.moviesList = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  getMovies,
  setMovies,
} = movieSlice.actions;
```

Where is the problem? Where to state that getMovies can accept an object as an argument?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the reducer functions must take the current state as their first parameter, and optionally the action that triggered the reducer. Also your reducer functions need to be returning the new state, not just any arbitrary data.

So your `getNames` reducer is going to get state where you're trying to get name, you're missing the action (2nd parameter), and you're not returning the new state.

To pass the object as as you have there, your reducer should look something like:

```js
   getMovies(state, {payload: {query, page}) {
      return {...state, moviesQuery: { query, page }};
   }
```

Comment: Thank u, but one question. What is `moviesQuery:`?

Comment: It's the arbitrary property name I decided to give the payload to. You can choose any place in your state to store the data (or transform it, etc, etc, etc)

Comment: You should go step by step through a redux tutorial until you understand it. It will help.